# How do I draw a line between all the drawn points?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a paint event I did:

```
List<Point> drawPoints = GetDrawPoints();

if (drawPoints.Count > 1)
{
    foreach (Point p in drawPoints)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, p.X - 2, p.Y - 2, 4, 4);
    }
}
```

But instead of drawing lines between the subsequential points, it's drawing two lines from same place to each point.

I want to connect all point with a single line.

Comment: Have you considered trying to reference the previous point?

Comment: Have a look at `DrawLines()` and `DrawPolygon()`

Comment: Right found this: e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, drawPoints.ToArray()); working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [DrawLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass the List as an array:

```
if (drawPoints.Count > 1)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, drawPoints.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question in a way. To draw a line you need at the very least two points. But you keep drawing your news lines between the sames locations. (your variable point and a point located in (4;4)). You need to keep updating two points in your foreach and print them properly.

Better yet, use the [DrawLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function, and give your list of points away. with something like :

```
 e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, drawPoints.ToArray());
```